# chamar um método da main activity a partir de um botão do Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-activity

Estou usando uma activity padrao do android, a "Navigation Drawer Activity", e Existe um botão  na navigation bar

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_example) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Example action.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        //getActivity().drawGraph();
        return true;
    }
```

E eu gostaria de chamar o método drawGraphic() da minha main activity somente ao apertar o botao

Vale ressaltar que essa navigation bar é um fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente:

```
((Nome da Sua Activity)getActivity()).drawGraph();
```

Comment: @Andrey Realmente não tenho certeza se o código acima resolve o problema, mas fazer um *cast* de um tipo genérico para um específico é uma saída para chamar algum método do tipo específico. Porém, concordo que o ideal seria o Mateus explicar o código, de forma que a resposta tenha uma utilidade mais abrangente.

Comment: Funcionou. Muito obrigado. Depois vou pesquisar o porquê de ter funcionado.